# Operators such that $\langle Ax,x \rangle=-\langle x,Ax \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. We consider the differential equation:
$$x'(t)=Ax(t), \ \ \ t\in\mathbb{R}$$
where $A$ is a bounded operator on $X$.

If $X$ is a Hilbert space, and  $x(t)$ is a solution of the differential equation, then 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|^2=\langle Ax(t),x(t) \rangle+\langle x(t),Ax(t) \rangle$$
If the operator $A$ has the property $\langle Ax,x \rangle=-\langle x,Ax \rangle$, then we will get 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|^2=0,$$
which means $|x(t)|$ is constant.

So the condition $\langle Ax,x \rangle=-\langle x,Ax \rangle$ makes $|x(t)|$ constant for every $x(t)$ solution.

Can we find a weaker property on $A$ which will make $|x(t)|$ constant only for the bounded solutions on $\mathbb{R}$? Is there any reference which deals with these problems ?

Note: I am not looking for evident conditions like: The only bounded solution is $0$.

Comment: You are, equivalently, considering the class of operators $A$ such that $\langle Ax,x \rangle$ is purely imaginary.  A necessary condition is that $A$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues.  A sufficient condition is for $A$ to be skew-Hermitian.

Comment: Wait. It is not true that $x(t)$ must be constant if $A$ is skew-adjoint. (If that were true quantum mechanics would be trivial). It is the *norm* $\lVert x(t)\rVert$ that is constant. Think at the prototypical example, the harmonic oscillator $$\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \dot{x}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Its orbits in the phase plane $(x, \dot{x})$ are circumferences, that is, loci of points of constant distance from the origin.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry I will fix this catastrophic error.

Comment: "Will make only the bounded solutions constant". Sure. For a generic linear operator, the only bounded solution is $x(t) \equiv 0$. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY No, I am looking for some non trivial conditions.

Comment: Let me rephrase. You say you want all bounded solutions to have constant modulus. Any operator for which the only bounded solution is $x(t)\equiv 0$, meets that criterion (example: $A=I$). If you do not actually want such operators, the question  should be made more precise.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY I will precise this.

Comment: If $\|x(t)\|=\|x_{0}\|$ for all $t \ge 0$, and if $x(0)=x_{0}$ must be allowed to be arbitrarily chosen in $\mathcal{D}(A)$, then it does follow that $(Ax_{0},x_{0})+(x_{0},Ax_{0})=0$ must hold for all allowed $x_{0}\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. So, $A$ must be skew symmetric. Normally you would want $\|x_{0}\|=1$, but that doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: @T.A.E. Yes, you are right, this shows that we cannot escape from the skew symmetry. Thanks.